# nginx index derective not working

Tags: php, nginx

```
location /bo/ {
    root /var/www/mysite/web/bo/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index /bo/index.php; # it's not work
}

location  / {
    root /var/www/mysite/web/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.php; # it's work
}

location  ~ \.php$  {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

When I request `mysite.com/` I get response from my `index.php`, but when I request `mysite.com/bo/` I get not found error, maybe `index` derictive do not work? or secondari derictive updated first `index` derictive. I have 1 question . on first: how to don't inter in `location /` if in request exist `/bo/`?

---

#### Solved

I fix this trouble

```
location /bo/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/bo/ /bo/index.php?$args;
}
    
location  / {
    root /var/www/mysite/web/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.php; # it's work
}
    
location  ~ \.php$  {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: /bo/ index should be only `index index.php;` as well.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block

Answer (score 0):

You already specified `root` directory, so `index` must be a relative path. In your case `index index.php`.

```
location /bo/ {
    root /var/www/mysite/web/bo/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.php;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have `/var/www/mysite/web/bo/index.php` file. And also check you log file

Comment: thank you for feedback, I fix this error replace `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` to `try_files $uri $uri/bo/ /bo/index.php?$args;` and remove `root` and `index` derective..